# calling another frame ASP.NET C# function with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, mono, ext.net

in my MainFrame.aspx i have create the panel with load ajaxFrm.aspx

```
<ext:Panel ID="pnlAjax" runat="server" Height="30" Title="" Header="false" Frame="true">  
<AutoLoad Url="ajaxFrm.aspx" Mode="IFrame" ShowMask="false" />  
</ext:Panel>
```

i the ajaxFrm.aspx having this C# `LoadVehStore2` Function

```
function LoadVehStore2() {

}
```

in MainFrame.aspx i have a javascript when the page are load then run the javascript

```
frmAjax = parent.frames["pnlAjax"];
frmAjax.LoadVehStore2();
```

this thing can work proper in IIS,
but in Ubuntu Mono 3.3.0 are fail, why? how to solve this?

Comment: might help if you mentioned which version of mono you were using.

Comment: @MystereMan Mono 3.30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not C#. It's Javascript. I doubt that the problem is with Mono, I suspect the problem is with the browser.

Since the iframe is created by Ext.Net you have to reference it with the name Ext.Net gives to it. To get the name just use the developer tools of the browser, but it should be `pnlAjax_IFrame`. 
Or, if it's the only iframe in the parent page you'd better reference it by id:

```
frmAjax = parent.frames[0].LoadVehStore2();
```

Comment: does not help, same error `LoadVehStore2() is not a function`. and it's C# function, not javascript

Comment: LoadVehStore2 is declared as a JS function in your code above.